# Can't get Google Advertising id on first device boot

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my app, I need to get the user's `Google advertising ID`.

I am using the code from https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html.

My problem is that my app can run immediately after the first launch.
However, since `Google Play Services` takes a while to update, I fail trying to get the error below

```
> (Google play services is out of date...
> GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not
> available).
```

But the google *advertising ID* does exist before that update (I can see it when going to the "Google Settings" app).

Is there a way to get the `Google Advertiser Id` before `Google Play services` get to update?

The error I get:

```
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6587000 but found 4323038
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6587000 but found 4323038
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
W/System.err﹕ com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not available
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.C(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.h(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.b(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.aaa.bbb.utils.IDUtils$1.doInBackground(IDUtils.java:36)
W/System.err﹕ at com.aaa.bbb.utils.IDUtils$1.doInBackground(IDUtils.java:28)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415c8ba8)
W/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Missing tracking id (&tid) parameter.
W/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: IllegalStateException getting Ad Id Info. If you would like to see Audience reports, please ensure that you have added '<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />' to your application manifest file. See http://goo.gl/naFqQk for details.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6587000 but found 4323038
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6587000 but found 4323038
```

Comment: What `IDE` are you using?

Comment: I'm using Android studio

Comment: i see on yout `logcat` saying `please ensure that you have added '<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />'`. Have you checked if you are using the right `Google API`

Comment: I have   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
in my manifest...

And for the record, I am able to get the advertising id after Google Play Services updates

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that Google Play Services version 4.323038 (which is installed on your device) does include the Advertising ID and you do have to use it after checking isLimitAdTrackingEnabled().

But in order to extract it you would have to use an older version of the com.google.android.gms library :) So, you can either rebuild the project using a downgraded Google play services SDK (which is not a good idea) or send the user to update his version and retry your attempt during the next session.

Comment: I don't want the user to perform such an action... and also, building with an older version of Play Services is not an option because I don't know what is the version of Play Services that is installed on a device before the upgrade

Comment: You could probably use the first SDK version that introduces the Advertising ID (which is Google Play Services 4.0) [ http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html ] since in case the user has an older version, you may fall back to using a persistent or proprietary identifier [ https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248 ]